# Unit Testing for Data Annotation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, data-annotations

I have added data annotation for model, find the code,

```
public class DownloadInfo
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Email]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write unit testing for this data annotation by giving the invalid email id like below.

```
    [Test]
    public void InvalidTestPost()
    {
        TestControllerBuilder builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
        DownloadController downloadController = builder.CreateController<DownloadController>();
        
        DownloadInfo downloadInfo = new DownloadInfo();
        downloadInfo.Email= "some invaild email";

        Assert.IsTrue(!downloadController.ModelState.IsValid);
    }
```

How can I unit test for data annotation?

Answer (score 0):

An obvious old question but here is an answer in case anyone is looking still.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DataAnnotationsTesting;

namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class OurDataValidationClassShould
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ReturnAnErrorIfAnEmailIsInvalid()
        {
            DownloadInfo downloadInfo = new DownloadInfo()
            {
                Email = "Invalid Email",
                Name = "Name"
            };

            Validator.ValidateObject(downloadInfo, new ValidationContext(downloadInfo, null, null) { MemberName = "Email" });
        }
    }
}
```